# bad_alloc uncatchable but works on other compilers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have reduced some broken code of mine into this:

```
// bad_alloc standard exception
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    cout << "dd: ";
    cin >> i;
    try
    {
        int* student = new int[i];
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Bad memory allocation" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Im using VS Express 13 Desktop. The problem i'm having is that if you type in `-1`, a bad_alloc exception is thrown internally, but is not caught. I know it is thrown because the output says the following:

```
First-chance exception at 0x7789C42D in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0046FB28.
```

The real kicker? If you copy and paste that code into another compiler like http://www.cpp.sh, it works fine.

I know this seems like it might be a VS bug, but my question is how do I work around it in the meantime?

How are we supposed to catch bad_alloc exceptions gracefully?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at your program's output and not the debugger's output?  That message is expected to show up in the debugger's output, but the exception should be caught.

Comment: it is the debuggers output yes, sorry for being unclear. the program itself crashes with a microsoft error box, rather than just exiting. no console output prints.

Comment: Works for me in release mode.

Comment: tried that, same problem. whats weird is after the debugger error, if you click ignore, the code is reached. why did ms decide to handle an error and not let the program continue (me handle the error)?

Comment: hold on a second. the problem vanished. it does work in release mode now. god only knows why waiting a few hours made it go away.

Comment: If there was an "ignore" button, perhaps you've configured the debugger to break on first chance exceptions?

Comment: i never touched any settings. and i ran it in release mode. i changed to release mode, rebuilt the program, opened the release folder in windows explorer, opened cmd there, and ran the exe. and the debugger error handler still showed, meaning it was still hooked for whatever reason. and now the error is gone. works fine. catch and all.

Comment: someone close this please or answer it cause i dont know how.